# Python - how to take the max length from a value of dictionary? Without lambda

Tags: python, dictionary, key, max

Let us say I have this function:

```
    def frequent_base(self):
        dict = {}    
        for i in range(len(self.items)):
            if self.items[i].base not in dict:
                dict[self.items[i].base] = [(self.items[i].value)]
            else:
                dict[self.items[i].base] += [(self.items[i].base)]
        return max(len(dict[self.items]), key=len(d))
```

Now, I can make it complicated and build a function which returns me index and such..
but it is bad coding and bad habit and takes long time ( especially in a test ).
How do I take the length?
let us say I have:
key1 with length 3 of value ( key1 has 3 values )
key2 with length 4 of value  ( key 2 has 4 values )
key3 with length 2 of value ( key 3 has 2 values )

How do I take, not the key itself, not the value itself, but the len of values of key? which is 4 in this case.
or how do I take the key itself and then say length of value of that key? But I want to use Max function, I need to understand how to use that function good, with the key.

I will write and make myself super clear:

```
dict[1] = [1,2,3]  
dict[2] = [1,2,3,4,5]  
dict[3] = [1,2,3,7,8,9,10]   
dict = {1: [1,2,3], 2:[1,2,3,4,5], 3:[1,2,3,7,8,9,10]}
```

I wish to return not dict[3], not 3, not the list of dict[3] it self.
I wish to return the length of the dict[3], which is 7

---

def frequent_base(self):
dict = {}
for i in range(len(self.items)):
if self.items[i].base not in dict:
dict[self.items[i].base] = [(self.items[i].value)]
else:
dict[self.items[i].base] += [(self.items[i].base)]
def key_for_len(dictionary):
return dictionary[1]
return max(dict.items(), key= key_for_len)

I am received error

Comment: Why not with lambda?

Comment: It's helpful that you provided some sample inputs vs. outputs

Comment: @matszwecja we have not learned lambda, thus, not allowed to use it + even If I will write with lambda here, how it will help me? since I dont know how to use it, it will be useless, since in the test I wont use it. Plus I dont have time to study it, the test is in a few days :\ I rather spend time on doing some exercises.

Comment: @DanielHao there is not sample inputs or sample outputs. 
I just need to take the highest len of the value ( which is 4 in the case I gave ), I said just ( like its easy, but its hard ).

Comment: @DanielHao I dont know also how to provide it, that is the problem :\
Its kind of an exercise which I "upgraded", I made it lets say, there is no such exercises, I am just trying new stuff to learn.

Comment: "there is not sample inputs or sample outputs" - Does that mean you don't know what your code is supposed to be doing? If there aren't any provided than create your own examples so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: @matszwecja I know what is my code to do, I just edited my question, please take a look and then say if its not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only thing you seem to need is maximal length amongst the values of your dictionary. You can easily get all the values using `d.values()` (`d.items()` would give you `(key, value)` tuples, which are harder to compare). Now we can easily calculate lengths of each value with generator comprehension (very much like list comprehension, which would also work) - `len(v) for v in d.values()`. Now we have an iterable with all the lengths, so it's just a matter of finding the maximum -

```
max(len(v) for v in d.values())
```

Should you need to get key or value with maximum length, we'd have to take a slightly different approach - we can use `max` `key =` argument to specify how we decide which element in the iterable is maximal - it is obvious when we are trying to get a maximum from few numbers, but not when we try to decide if `(1, 3)` is bigger than `(2, 2)` - in such case, we need to create a function that maps our items to easily comparable things like a number. In this case, we'd have tuples of `(key, value)` and we are comparing length of value - thus our function would be

```
def lenOfValue(kv):
    return len(kv[1]) # kv[1] - 2nd element of a (key, value) tuple
```

*code(1)*

Then we pass that to max:

```
print(max(d.items(), key = lenOfValue))
```

And we get `(2, [3, 4, 5, 6])`

***Bonus:*** `lambda`

Lambdas can be used here, which are really just a shorthand that lets us skip defining whole another function that we will probably never use again.
This code would be functionally exactly the same.

```
print(max(d.items(), key = lambda kv: len(kv[1])))
```

*code(2)*

Lambdas are nothing very complicated, being just a notation for creating simple, one-liner functions without all the bother of a `def` block, return etc.
Because Python's functions are objects like nearly anything else, this piece of code:

```
lenOfValue = lambda kv: len(kv[1])
```

really is in no way different that our previously used more lengthy definition of:

```
def lenOfValue(kv):
    return len(kv[1])
```

It saves us few words and shows us the middle step between code(1) and code(2).

Comment: I thought of it, but it is a problem.
I dont have a functional dictionary, I create the dictionary in my main function.
It means I have to recreate the dictionary on an another function.

Comment: Also, I dont understand why x[1] will return me the value??
Also, it wont work me, I will edit now at post what I did, please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: @LearningToCode please see edit

Comment: I saw,  but I still want to understand, since my point here is not to solve only, but to learn. but I will try now and update

Comment: Actually yea, its enough, thanks :)
But still i want to understand, and if can, please explain me why that line of code works? I am having hard time understanding key= stuff

Comment: @LearningToCode Sure, I'll edit out the first part and clarify what it does.

Comment: Thanks. If you can, explain both of those, the one with the short that works, and the first you did.

Comment: Thanks, but with how you did before, with the helper function that return x[1], what is that? can you explain that way also? because it didnt work to me :\

Comment: @LearningToCode here, probably slightly more verbose answer than it was necessary.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, if I could double answer and V, I would have done it. Thanks!!

Comment: Just a last question, since you basically answered all:
Why is kv[1] giving me the value? How does python understand it as the dictionary tuple? I mean, when I put kv[0] it gave me bad answer, why? what does it do? what I get if I do kv[0]?

Comment: `.items()` gives you iterator over `(key, value)` tuples. Tuples are indexed similiarly to lists, so `kv[0]` gives you 1st element - `key` and `kv[1]` gives you 2nd element - `value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a_dict = {'some_key':[67,30,10], 'another_key':[87]}


max({ (k,len(v)) for k,v in a_dict.items() })

('some_key', 3)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.
I dont know how to use one liner, but I will check now on my pycharm and test it, thanks :)

Comment: This doesn't work as intended. It returns `some_key` only because `'some_key'` string > `'another_key'` string, not because of values.